# Uploading/Creating Directories on a webDAV server via Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, upload, webdav, owncloud

Hello everyone I am making a visual basic application to synchronise files and folders with a webDAV server however I am having trouble uploading/creating directories in the server but not with uploading files this is the code I am using to try to create directories on the server.

```
Private Sub FldrSync()
    PictureBox1.Location = New Point(12, 161)
    PictureBox1.Size = New Point(756, 147)
    PictureBox1.Visible = True
    Dim folderDlg As New FolderBrowserDialog
    folderDlg.SelectedPath = TextBox1.Text
    TextBox1.Text = folderDlg.SelectedPath
    Dim root As Environment.SpecialFolder = folderDlg.RootFolder
    For Each foundFile As String In Directory.GetDirectories(folderDlg.SelectedPath)

        ListBox1.Items.Add(foundFile)
        Dim check As String = _
        System.IO.Path.GetFileName(foundFile)

        Dim fileToUpload As String = foundFile
        Dim fileLength As Long = 0

        Dim url As String = TextBox2.Text
        Dim port As String = ""

        'If the port was provided, then insert it into the url.
        If port <> "" Then

            'Insert the port into the Url
            'https://www.example.com:80/directory
            Dim u As New Uri(url)

            'Get the host (example: "www.example.com")
            Dim host As String = u.Host

            'Replace the host with the host:port
            url = url.Replace(host, host & ":" & port)

        End If

        url = url.TrimEnd("/"c) & "/" & IO.Path.GetFileName(fileToUpload)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(url)

        Dim userName As String = TextBox4.Text
        Dim password As String = TextBox3.Text

        'Create the request
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = _
             DirectCast(System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)

        'Set the User Name and Password
        request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(userName, password)

        'Let the server know we want to "put" a file on it
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Put

        'Set the length of the content (file) we are sending
        request.ContentLength = fileLength


        '*** This is required for our WebDav server ***
        request.SendChunked = True
        request.Headers.Add("Translate: f")
        request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = True


        'Send the request to the server, and get the 
        ' server's (file) Stream in return.
        Dim s As IO.Stream = request.GetRequestStream()

        'Open the file so we can read the data from it

        'Create the buffer for storing the bytes read from the file
        Dim byteTransferRate As Integer = 1024
        Dim bytes(byteTransferRate - 1) As Byte
        Dim bytesRead As Integer = 0
        Dim totalBytesRead As Long = 0

        'Read from the file and write it to the server's stream.
        Do
            'Read from the file
            bytesRead = 0

            If bytesRead > 0 Then

                totalBytesRead += bytesRead

                'Write to stream
                s.Write(bytes, 0, bytesRead)

            End If

        Loop While bytesRead > 0

        'Close the server stream
        s.Close()
        s.Dispose()
        s = Nothing

        'Close the file

        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

        'Get the StatusCode from the server's Response
        Dim code As HttpStatusCode = response.StatusCode

        'Close the response
        response.Close()
        response = Nothing

        'Validate the uploaded file.
        ' Check the totalBytesRead and the fileLength: Both must be an exact match.
        '
        ' Check the StatusCode from the server and make sure the file was "Created"
        ' Note: There are many different possible status codes. You can choose
        ' which ones you want to test for by looking at the "HttpStatusCode" enumerator.
        If totalBytesRead = fileLength AndAlso _
            code = HttpStatusCode.Created Then

            MessageBox.Show("The file has uploaded successfully!", "Upload Complete", _
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

        Else

            MessageBox.Show("The file did not upload successfully.", _
                "Upload Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)

        End If
    Next
    PictureBox1.Location = New Point(494, 5)
    PictureBox1.Size = New Point(28, 20)
    PictureBox1.Visible = False
End Sub
```

I have found a way to upload folders to the webDAV server but I am using root permissions because the webDAV folder runs off an ownCloud server which means the user files are in a permission setting to nobody:nobody. However the folders do upload but the user cannot edit, delete, or create files in them. The code for this is below.

Visual Basic

```
Private Sub CreateFolders()
    PictureBox1.Location = New Point(12, 161)
    PictureBox1.Size = New Point(756, 147)
    PictureBox1.Visible = True
    Dim folderDlg As New FolderBrowserDialog
    folderDlg.SelectedPath = TextBox1.Text
    TextBox1.Text = folderDlg.SelectedPath
    Dim root As Environment.SpecialFolder = folderDlg.RootFolder
    For Each foundFile As String In Directory.GetFiles(folderDlg.SelectedPath)

        ListBox1.Items.Add(foundFile)
        Dim check As String = _
        System.IO.Path.GetFileName(foundFile)

        WebBrowser2.Navigate("http://myserver/BOXSYNC/foldercreate.php?localfolder=" & TextBox1.Text & "&boxfolder=" & TextBox2.Text & "&username=" & TextBox4.Text & "&password=" & TextBox3.Text & "&filename=" & check & "&foldername=" & FldrName.Text)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(check)
    Next
    PictureBox1.Location = New Point(494, 5)
    PictureBox1.Size = New Point(28, 20)
    PictureBox1.Visible = False
End Sub
```

PHP

```
<?php
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');

include('Net/SSH2.php');
include('Net/SFTP.php');
?>
<?php

$local = $_GET['localfolder'];
echo $local;
echo "<br>";

$box = $_GET['boxfolder'];
echo $box;
echo "<br>";

$box = str_replace("https://box.com/remote.php/webdav/","",$box);
echo $box;
echo "<br>";

$file = $_GET['filename'];
echo $file;
echo "<br>";

$user = $_GET['username'];
echo $user;
echo "<br>";

$sftp = new Net_SFTP('the.hostingsite.com');
if (!$sftp->login('root', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
$media_path = '/home/box/public_html/data/'.$user.'/files/'.$box.'/'.$file;
$origin_path = '/home/box/public_html/data/'.$user.'/files/'.$box;

$sftp->mkdir($media_path);
echo $media_path;
echo "<br>";
$sftp->chown($media_path, 'nobody');
echo "<br>";
$sftp->chmod($media_path, 0755);
$sftp->chown($media_path, 'nobody', true);
$sftp->chgrp($media_path, 'nobody', true);
$sftp->chdir($media_path);
echo "<br>";
$file_name= $file;
$path = "/home/sites/php.net/public_html/sandbox/" . $file_name ;
$user_name = "box82";

chown($path, $user_name);

$stat = stat($path);
print_r(posix_getpwuid($stat['uid']));
?>

<form method="post" action="index.php" id="syncform" style="display:none;">

<input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="localfolder" value="<?php echo $local; ?>" />

<input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="boxfolder" value="<?php echo $box; ?>" />

<input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="username" value="<?php echo $user; ?>" />

<input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="password" value="" />

<input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="filename" value="<?php echo $file; ?>" />

<input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="foldername" value="" />

<input type="submit" id="sync" value="Sync" />

</form>
```

If you could help me that would be great!
Thank you.